# nested if statement inside for loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a nested if statement

```
for x in listsent:
    print(x)
    
    z = input()
    if z == 1:
        tag = "O"
        q = input()
        if q == 1:
            pos = "Q"
        elif q == 2:

            

    elif z == 2:
        tag = "Q"
        q = input()
        if q == 1:
            pos = "O"
        elif q == 2:
```

but when when I enter 1 in the first IF statement it takes me to the next item in the for loop instead of taking me to the second if statement

Comment: `input()` returns a string, not an int

Comment: Spend the time to learn how to use a debugger, and step through your code line by line, and watch what your variables are doing at each stage. You will find it altogether easier to find and solve problems with your code once you know how to do this.

Comment: Is this your real code? It looks invalid because there is nothing following the `elif q == 2:`

Answer (score 1):

Input returns a string, not an integer. To convert string to integer, use `z = int(input())` and `q = int(input())` wherever required

Comment: Or even better - don't convert it and just do `q=="1"` instead - one operation less, yet same output ;)